# Possible DNS Server memory leak

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, performance, windows-server-2012-r2, memory-leak

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 physical server running AD DS, DNS roles.
Very frequently DNS Server process starts consuming a lot of memory.

In `Task Manager > Details > Analyze wait chain` - I can see the following message:

"**One or more threads of dns.exe are waiting to finish network I/O.**"

[image]

If I then run Process Explorer - I can see a bunch of threads:

[image]

Due to above problem - users experience name resolution issues.

Once the DNS Server service is restarted - the issue is gone for some time.

Is there any known fix for this?

**`UPD1:`**

Server has 8GB of RAM totally and 2 vCPUs.

DNS Server process is using 1.7GB of RAM and 40-60% CPU.

[image]

Number of DNS queries varies from 40 to 100 per second.

[image]

Here is the statistics for the last 2.5h:

[image]

Comment: Hi ..just some question...How many query per seconds get your server? Is an authoritative DNS , if yes how many objects are inside?How much is your TTL?

Comment: Yes, the server is authoritative. TTL is 1 hour. I can't precisely tell you the # of queries per second so far. There are about 5k records totally.

Comment: You need to figure out how and wich Dns query reaching your server i by dumping and tracing the requests for fiveminute in a log ... There's no way before looking for patching and update

Comment: Do you mean network dump by e.g. WireShark or... ?

Comment: Yes...to try to sniff... (if you can use an external machine it's much better), the DNS is one of the favourite target in the last years and we had an evidence also in LAN because on large wifi network someone used an infected pc , you need to understand if depend from a microsoft bug, incorrect configuration or external cause.

Comment: There are a large number of DNS performance counters. Perfmon can help you understand the volume and type of queries your server is responding to.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this hotfix may help you
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3082532

Assume that you're running Microsoft DNS Services on Windows Server 2012 R2-based computers in an Active Directory Forest. You notice that the DNS service on Windows Server 2012 R2-based DNS servers consumes increasing amounts of memory, and then memory leak occurs. Additionally, the memory leaks by DNS may affect the performance of other components, services, and applications that are running on the same computer.

DNS hotfix has this prerequisite
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355