# FQDN ip address disappears on Windows Server 2012 so DC doesn't work

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

We have a server that works as  DNS, Domain Controller and Active Directory server. (Windows Server 2012)

The problem is that computers joined to the domain lose connection so they can’t login or they can't find the active directory.

We found that the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) IP's address disappears eventually (taking a value of `<Unknown>`).

Please see the image:

[image: Configuration window on DNS manager]

Also, we found that problem is solved (just temporary) changing the FQDN IP address by the server machine ip address, and flushing the DNS on all the computers joined to domain (ipconfig /flushdns). But this solution work for just a few minutes because the FQDN ip address get lost agains. (Could this be a good solution?)

What may be problem of this situation? And,

What may be the solution?
Thanks.

---

### EDIT 1

```
**Server IP Address**
169.250.0.1
DNS Server
169.250.0.1
```

**dcdiag /q** output

```
 An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC004000B
    Time Generated: 12/02/2015   10:09:20
    Event String:
    The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk2\DR5.
 An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC004000B
    Time Generated: 12/02/2015   10:09:21
    Event String:
    The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk2\DR5.
 ......................... SERVER failed test SystemLog
```

**nslookup -type=NS mysite.com** output

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server: Unknown
Address: ::1

mysite.com    nameserver - server.mysite.com
server.mysite.com internet address = 169.250.0.1
```

Comment: please post dcdiag /q results.

Comment: Hello @Daniel, dcdiag /q doesn't work. Neither dxdiag /q.

Comment: What is the server itself using for DNS? What are the clients using for DNS?

Comment: @joeqwerty, because I have a Domain Controller and Active Directory so the user clients joined to domain need to connect to the DNS server to resolve the Domain Name. (I followed the Microsoft tutorial to create a Domain Controller, at the final step, it's needed to create a DNS server).

Comment: Yes, I understand all about AD and DNS. I'm asking you to specifically tell me what the DNS client settings are set to on the server and the domain members.

Comment: @joeqwerty, The DNS settings on the clients are set to DNS server machine ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Does the zone also have an A record for itself?
it should look like:

(same as parent)      Host (A)        XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX    static

...and you must create it when the zone is created.
This can happen if this A record isn't there.
Note (XXX.XXX....) = IP address of local machine.
-larryc

Comment: Hello @Larryc. Yes, There is a A record with the local machine IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The nameserver/dc is in "mysite.com" zone, but the image is showing us the properties for  the "ux-industries.net" zone.
Did you edit any of the names in the image you posted?
How many forward lookup zones exist on the server, and what are they?
How is DCDIAG failing? If you're experiencing other system issues that prevent that command from running, those issues may also be causing DNS to not operate normally.

I don't recall if the IP on that tab comes from the A record directly or through the NS record (and then the A record).
When you're experiencing the problem, what is returned by these commands?

`nslookup -type=NS ux-industries.net
nslookup -type=NS mysite.com`

Is this OS 2012 R1 or R2?
Is the DC name the only name that sometimes has a resolution problem?
If many names fail after a time, and OS is 2012 R2, your DNS service may be dying due to a memory leak.
See the following:
[Possible DNS Server memory leak](https://serverfault.com/questions/737486/possible-dns-server-memory-leak/737700)
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3082532

**Edit Dec 03**

You seem to have a hard disk controller problem that needs attention. I would fix that first. Did your DNS problems start around the same time those errors started? Review system log for controller error history.
If your domain is named "mysite.com" why are you showing us properties of "ux-industries.net" zone? Very hard to troubleshoot DNS issues if you posting edited command output. What is "mysite.local" if you domain is named "mysite.com"?
That looks like only a small part of DCDIAG output. Could you post full output of DCDIAG
When the problem is occuring, what is the output of "NLTEST /dsquerydns"?
What kind of pattern does the problem follow, are there hours/days/weeks between the problem recurrance? Rebooting DC fixes problem?
Did you try applying the hotfix from my first response?

Comment: Hello @Craig620. I edited the image. I'd like to use mysite.com in Stackoverflow :). There are 2 Forward lookup Zones. (1 related to _msdcs.mysite.com and other for mysite.com. It is Windows Server 2012 R2. And DC is the only one that has a resolution.

Comment: please see the output `dcdiag` and `nslookup` command in the Question section. Thanks.